# Checking privacy and get users according to it in single query

Tags: php, mysql

I have write a query in which I'm checking if user set his privacy to everyone it will return that result, if user sets to network then current user in my case its 5 will check that user must be his friend or friend of friend and if its set to friend then user should be his friend:

I try this query but issue is its giving an error:

> #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

is there any way to write this query in different way and get appropriate result.

```
SELECT `U`.`UserGUID`, `U`.`FirstName`, `U`.`LastName`
    FROM (`Users` U)
    LEFT JOIN `UserPrivacy` UP ON `UP`.`UserID`=`U`.`UserID`
    WHERE `UP`.`PrivacyLabelKey` =  'group_invite'
    AND 
     IF(UP.Value='everyone',true,'')
     OR
     (UP.Value='network',U.UserID IN(SELECT F2.FriendID FROM Friends F JOIN Friends F2 ON F.FriendID = F2
    .UserID WHERE F.UserID = 5 AND F2.Status='1' AND F.Status='1' GROUP BY F2.FriendID),'')
     OR
     (UP.Value='friend',U.UserID IN(SELECT FriendID FROM Friends WHERE UserID=5 AND Status=1),'')

    AND U.UserID!=5
    GROUP BY `U`.`UserID`
```

Comment: `IF(UP.Value='everyone' OR (UP.Value='network',U.UserID IN(SELECT F2.FriendID FROM Friends F JOIN Friends F2 ON F.FriendID = F2
    .UserID WHERE F.UserID = 5 AND F2.Status='1' AND F.Status='1' GROUP BY F2.FriendID)) OR (UP.Value='friend',U.UserID IN(SELECT FriendID FROM Friends WHERE UserID=5 AND Status=1) )` ....update the query and give a try

Comment: please provide your table structure..with CREATE statement

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/388d4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT `U`.`UserGUID`, `U`.`FirstName`, `U`.`LastName`
    FROM (`Users` U)
    LEFT JOIN `UserPrivacy` UP ON `UP`.`UserID`=`U`.`UserID`
    WHERE `UP`.`PrivacyLabelKey` =  'group_invite'
    AND 
    IF(UP.Value='everyone',true, IF(UP.Value='network', U.UserID IN(SELECT F2.FriendID FROM Friends F JOIN Friends F2 ON F.FriendID = F2
    .UserID WHERE F.UserID = 5 AND F2.Status='1' AND F.Status='1' GROUP BY F2.FriendID), if(UP.Value='everyone',U.UserID IN(SELECT FriendID FROM Friends WHERE UserID=5 AND Status=1),'')))

    AND U.UserID!=5
    GROUP BY `U`.`UserID`
```